# Unknown button type 'help-xref' when trying to save content of buffer to emacs

Tags: emacs

I am using emacs 24.3 on ubuntu 12.04. 
I open 'M-x shell' and then run shell commands. After that I want to save the whole buffer to a file. So I did 'C-x C-s'. But when I do that, saving to file failed. I get this 'Unknown button type 'help-xref' on the status bar.

how can I fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Mention your emacs version (`M-x emacs-version`). Does this happen if you start from `emacs -Q`? If not, narrow down your init file, by bisecting it recursively, until you find the code that causes this to happen. Let us know here what you find.

Comment: I suspect that you maybe left something out from your recipe.  `C-x C-s` normally does not try to show `*Help*`, which is the kind of thing that tries to create help cross-reference buttons (links).  My crystal ball also tells me that the problem might be some 3rd-party library you are using that has not yet been updated for the incompatible change they introduced for Emacs 24.4 regarding macro `with-output-to-temp-buffer` (it no longer puts the buffer in help mode).  (This has bitten me, for instance.)

Comment: How can I fix this incompatible change 'with-output-to-temp=buffer'? without disable 3rd party library?

Comment: First, be sure that's what the problem is: narrow your init file by bisecting it recursively, to determine the code that leads to the problem.  If it is the problem then contact the maintainer of that library.  Emacs Dev should let users know how to fix this, in file `NEWS`.  (If they do not, it's a bug, IMHO.)

Comment: I have a blank .emacs file. I still get the same error when I do 'C-x C-s' to save shell mode output to a file.

Comment: Did you start from `emacs -Q`? If so, then use `M-x report-emacs-bug` to report just what you did before getting the error.

Comment: I was able to produce this error under 24.4 running under Windows 7. It appeared that I had inadvertantly inserted a 16-bit Unicode file into my buffer. When I deleted and retyped the first line of the insertion (maybe eliminating an invisible byte-order mark?) the problem went away. FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this error as well, and isolated it to non-ASCII characters in my buffer (e.g. `→` and `…`). I was able to resolve it via `M-x prefer-coding-system` 
→ `utf-8`